# Extension script not receiving messages from content script - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an event listener checking for mouse moves in the content script, which sends a chrome message to the popup.js extension script when detected (that is mouse moves). However, the popup.js script seems to not receive any of the messages passed from the content script. I had also set up a secondary message passing sequence from the popup to the content script which had worked for some reason.

Prints in the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener callback do not print when run.

popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request.selText);
  if (request.sender == "content" && request.selText == "disabled") {
    // Disabled for webpage - No action
  } else if (request.sender == "content" && request.selText !== 
    "disabled"){
    // Some action with request.selText
  }
});`
```

content.js:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({sender: "content", selText : ""});
}, false);
```

Secondary message passing (this works):

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {cTabSettings: true});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cTabSettings === true) {
      // Some action
    } else if (request.cTabSettings === false) {
      // Some action
    }
});
```

My expected result is that the request.selText field would be printed in the popup inspector tool, but it is not.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I imagine this is because popup scripts are active (and listening) only when the popup is open. After that, the only thing that will listen constantly are background scripts.

Comment: I just tested the extension with the popup still open and the print's still not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an empty function call at the end of my content script message passing callback and it just worked.

The code looks like this:

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({sender: "content", selText : ""}, 
     function () {});
```

Comment: This shouldn't change anything. The fact that it did work for you means there's a bug in Chrome or a different error in your code.